# run iperf broadcast traffic on linux

Tags: linux, wifi

I am in the domain 192.168.1.xxx. I need to send broadcast traffic from a pc connected to a accesspoint to the android device wirelessly after connecting with a network through WiFi.

running iperf command `iperf -c 192.168.1.255 -i 2 -t 60 -b 10000 -u` on a Ubuntu 12.04 machine and running the command `iperf -s -i 2 -u` in adb shell.
But the client is unable to get the broadcast traffic and gives error as :

```
 read failed : connection refused.
```

Answer (score 1):

you cannot use `iperf` in broadcast mode.

if you are just testing whether broadcast works, you could try something like

```
# server
netcat -l -u -p 54321

# host
echo "foo" | netcat -ub 192.168.1.255 54321
```

note however, that on [some systems](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=702204), `netcat` might not be able to go into broadcast mode, so you might end up writing your own networking code.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do iperf broadcast on linux.

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage DHCP's properties, DHCP is advertised with a broadcast DISCORVERY package, so by putting a DHCP-server and a DHCP-client (normal host) at the ends of your network you can test broadcast traffic within it.
If you get an address -> you're OK
If you keep waiting and nothing happens -> something went wrong

Hope this helps you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Connection refused generally happens when the server and client are not on the same network or make sure the server IP address that you are specifying in the client is correct.